# Enabling Pyqt5 Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I added Vertical Scroll bar to my PYqt5 window but not working.
Here is my UI

Output of the UI

[image]

Output of the UI

[image]

here is the code

```
self.verticalScrollBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.verticalScrollBar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(13, 39))
self.verticalScrollBar.setStatusTip("")
self.verticalScrollBar.setSliderPosition(9)
self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
```

Comment: please share a [mcve]

Comment: How do you think I can add vertical scrollbar to main window in pyqt5

Comment: That depends on the structure of your widgets so I ask you to provide a [mcve]